# A pumping lemma for deterministic context-free languages?

Tags: context-free, proof-techniques, pumping-lemma

The pumping lemma for regular languages can be used to prove that certain languages are not regular, and the pumping lemma for context-free languages (along with Ogden's lemma) can be used to prove that certain languages are not context-free.

Is there a pumping lemma for *deterministic* context-free languages?  That is, is there a lemma akin to the pumping lemma that can be used to show that a language is not a DCFL?  I'm curious because almost all of the proof techniques I know to show that a language is not a DCFL are really complicated, and I was hoping that there was an easier technique.

Comment: There are some [related questions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=deterministic+context+free) that may or may not be relevant.

Comment: Computer scientists may be sadists, but they aren't are all masochists who use over-complicated proof techniques where simpler ones are known...

Comment: vonbrand: But any mathematician or computer scientist might use over-complicated proof techniques if simpler ones are not yet known or not known to him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There *is* a Pumping Lemma specifically for DCFL, under the title "A Pumping Lemma for Deterministic Context-Free Languages", by Sheng Yu; Information Processing Letters 31 (1989) 47-51, doi [10.1016/0020-0190(89)90108-7](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190%2889%2990108-7). With this explicit title I must apologize that I missed it!

The online copy unfortunately has a blank spot in one of the formula, so I hope I reconstructed the result properly. Below ${}^{(1)}y$ is the first symbol of $y$ (when it exists) or $\varepsilon$ (if $y=\varepsilon$).

**Lemma 1** (Pumping Lemma). Let $L$ be a DCFL. Then there exists a constant $C$ for $L$ such that for any pair of words $w,w'\in $ if

(1) $w=xy$ [?] and $w'=xz$, $|x|>C$ and

(2) ${}^{(1)}y = {}^{(1)}z $, [?]

then either (3) or (4) is true:

(3) there is a factorization $x=x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5$, $|x_2x_4|\ge 1$ and $|x_2x_3x_4|\le C$, such that for all $i\ge 0$ $x_1x^i_2x_3x^i_4x_5y$ and $x_1x^i_2x_3x^i_4x_5z$  are in $L$;

(4) there exist factorizations $x=x_1x_2x_3$, $y=y_1y_2y_3$ and $z=z_1z_2z_3$,  $|x_2|\ge 1$ and $|x_2x_3|\le C$, such that for all $i\ge 0$ $x_1x^i_2x_3y_1y^i_2y_3$ and $x_1x^i_2x_3z_1z^i_2z_3$ are in $L$.

Two applications of the Lemma are given: $\{ a^ib^i \mid i\ge 0 \} \cup \{ a^ib^{2i}  \mid i\ge 0 \}$ as well as $\{ w\in\{a,b\}^* \mid w=uv, |u|=|v|, \mbox{ and } v \mbox{ contains an } a \}$ are not DCFL.
The proof uses the fact that each DCFL has an LR(1) grammar in Greibach normal form.

Comment: I hope you can use it. It is even more complicated to state than the known pumping lemma.