# Can you create a deterministic PDA for non-palindomes?

Tags: pushdown-automata

Using non-determinism to create a PDA to recognize non-palindromes is easy.[image]

My first instinct was to say yes, but it would be extremely complicated. After thinking about it, I don't think you could.

Answer (score 2):

The language of palindromes isn't [DCFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language), see for example [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11598/prove-no-dpda-accepts-language-of-even-lengthed-palindromes), which proves this for the closely related language of even length palindromes. Since DCFL are closed under complementation, it follows that your language is not DCFL.