# Stuck with shift-reduce conflicts on yacc on grammar to generate palindromic strings on {0,1}

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I have written a yacc program for generating palindromic strings consisting of 0s and 1s. Here is the rules section of the yacc program below:

```
%%
program: expr NL { printf("Valid string.\n"); exit(0); }
;
expr: ZERO expr ZERO
| ONE expr ONE 
| ZERO 
| ONE
|
;
%%
```

Here `ZERO` is the token representing 0, `ONE` is the token representing 1, and `NL` represents `\n`. Using yacc on the above grammar, I'm given the following warnings.

```
yacc -dt --verbose 7b.y
7b.y: warning: 4 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
7b.y: warning: 2 reduce/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-rr]
```

To the best of my knowledge, the grammar above seems to be unambiguous. My questions are:

1. Why is yacc giving me this error?
2. What should I change to resolve this?

Here are the complete lex and yacc programs if they should help:

Lex:

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
void yyerror(char *);
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[0] { yylval = 0; return ZERO; }
[1] { yylval = 1; return ONE; }
\n { return NL; }
. yyerror("invalid character");
%%
int yywrap(void) {
return 1;
}
```

Yacc:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);
%}
%token ZERO ONE NL
%%
program: expr NL { printf("Valid string.\n"); exit(0); }
;
expr: ZERO expr ZERO
| ONE expr ONE 
| ZERO 
| ONE
|
;
%%
void yyerror(char *s) {
fprintf(stderr, "Invalid string.\n");
}
int main(void) {
yyparse();
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: (Consider giving more to look-ahead to.)

Comment: @greybeard sorry I'm new to stackexchange. What does "look-ahead to" mean?

Comment: (That has been a lame pun on the method "YACC parsers" use to resolve conflicts.) Have another look at your last rule: Can you imagine *any* rule not having a conflict with this one? How can you fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar is, as you say, unambiguous. But it is not *deterministic*. LR parsers with bounded lookahead can only recognise deterministic languages; since not all unambiguous context-free languages are deterministic, LR parsers cannot recognise all unambiguous context-free languages.

Intuitively, palindromes are non-deterministic because the parser must switch states precisely at the middle of the input, but there is no way to tell where the middle of a sentence is until you know where the end is, which is obviously not possible with bounded lookahead.

Proving that the language of palindromes is not deterministic is a bit of work. You probably won't find the proof in a textbook oriented towards writing compilers, such as the Dragon Book, but if you are studying formal language theory you might be working with a more theory-oriented textbook (such as Hopcroft and Ullman.) There is a proof that the language of even-length palindromes is non-deterministic [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11598/prove-no-dpda-accepts-language-of-even-lengthed-palindromes), and extending the proof to the language of all palindromes is not that difficult.

Comment: Congrats on the recent 10k @rici :)