# Paper with proof that $L=\{ a^n b^n \mid n \geq 0 \} \cup \{ a^n b^{2n} \mid n \geq 0 \}$ is not Deterministic Context Free?

Tags: formal-languages, reference-request, automata, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

[These lecture slides](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/modcomp/fall2005/slides/DPDA.ppt&ei=qI6mUeD6KaKOigLr-YH4Cg&usg=AFQjCNHdu1SacbRI9CaOjOvXxzNziaHtEQ&sig2=DLSgGZ-VegxX1lFVSTZTCw&bvm=bv.47244034,d.cGE) sketch a proof that $L=\{ a^n b^n \mid n \geq 0 \} \cup  \{ a^n b^{2n} \mid n \geq 0 \}$
cannot be accepted by any Deterministic Pushdown Automaton. Unfortunately, the slides give no references as to where the proof comes from.

I was wondering, does anybody know of an academic paper or textbook that gives a full proof? I'd love to be able to cite it, but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: As a note: the slides follow the same argument as the one I use in a related [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/a-pumping-lemma-for-deterministic-context-free-languages/10976#10976) on Pumping Lemma's for deterministic CFL. (This is a non-pumping argument of course.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result is proved in [Ginsburg and Greibach, *Deterministic context free languages*, Inform. Control 9(6), 620–648, 1966](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995866800190), Theorem 4.1 on page 24 (643). However, the proof looks somewhat different.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I'd seen references to that paper but had trouble finding a PDF copy.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you find that? Did you just know offhand what paper it was in, or did you search for it somehow? I'm trying to develop my paper-searching abilities...

Comment: I googled "deterministic context free" and it was one of the top results. The abstract didn't look too promising, but in the introduction they mention this result.