# Proof $\{u\colon |u| \text{ is odd and $b$ is in the middle}\}$ is not deterministic

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, automata

Without using pumping lemma for deterministic context-free languages I need to prove that the language $\{u\colon |u| \text{ is odd and $b$ is in the middle}\}$ is not deterministic.

Someone suggested me that I could try to deduce that if it were deterministic then the language $\{a^nb^nc^n\colon n\ge0\}$ would be context-free. But I don't really see how to use it.

Comment: What kind of argument are you allowed to use?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus just some argument that does not use pumping lemma

Comment: Well, you can include a proof of the pumping lemma and then you're fine.

Comment: Take a look at the technique suggested here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/38476/683.

Comment: Once you have a proof, please answer your own question.